# Animators may only be run on Looper threads on Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, multithreading, actionbarsherlock

I wanted to hide the action bar after the 1 second delay,

```
Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
```

Getting crash after I ran the code..

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on
>   Looper threads

Is there any solution for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: use a Handler and postDelayed()

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved it by using

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // Your Code
}
}, 1000);
```

Use this because the parameterless constructer handler is deprecated.

Comment: Hello @OmKumar Yadav, thank you for contributing to stackoverflow, please be more elaborate in your answers, provide explanations as much as possible. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for tips