# Animators may only be run on Looper threads Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-animation

I'm trying to animate something when a task is completed. The problem here is I get this error message:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1004)
   at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animatePropertyBy(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:965)
   at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animateProperty(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:921)
   at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.alpha(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:735)
   at com.design.zaton.prototypei.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:93)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The app worked fine before with the same exact code but now it simply doesn't. I'm really confused.

Here's where the error happens:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String s = getGiphyViews(String.valueOf(mEdit.getText()));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                result.setText(s);
            }
        });

        loading.animate()
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(100);

        done.animate()
                .scaleY(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .setDuration(300);
    }
}).start();
```

The error outlines the `loading.animate()` method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code
            }
});
```

You have to execute the code in the UI Thread

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer, as you don't have to add a delay. PS - If using this in a fragment, you'd use `requireActivity().runOnUiThread(...)`;

Answer (score 31):

[Looper threads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) are threads in Android that permanently loop (or until you cancel them).  They work in conjunction with [Handlers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) which will post and send messages to `Looper` threads.  Animators use heavy use of Looper threads because they perform their actions in repeated cycles.  This allows the animator to not block after you press "start" so you can continue to perform other actions.

To further complicate matters, you most likely are performing animations on `View` objects.  These can only be run on the main UI thread (which happens to be the biggest `Looper` thread of them all).  So, you can not run these animations on separate threads like you are trying.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the main-UI-thread (usable via calling `runOnUiThread`) is the biggest `Looper` thread.

Answer (score 27):

I think, there has been a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804163/2065039)** for this using `Handler`. You can use `postDelayed` to minimal as `100` and run your animating tasks. In your case it would be:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        final String s = getGiphyViews(String.valueOf(mEdit.getText()));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                result.setText(s);
            }
        });

        loading.animate()
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(100);

        done.animate()
                .scaleY(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .setDuration(300);
     }
}, 100);
```

I had this problem today and above work resolved the problem. I would love to hear from anyone if there is any problem with this method.

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin**

If you still want to use a delay (or not)

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    // Your Code
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put Code Where Are getting error and doing any network operations

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // add your code here 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you add little explanation on how to use your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a main handler instance in your activity and override handle message method. you can save a handler quote in your work thread.When you finished work you can use handler to send a message and you receive message in handle message method. To start animation from handler message method and so on...