# How to record a video of a Jetpack Compose @Composable function without blocking UI thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

## Context

I have a Jetpack Compose `@Composable` function that has a `AndroidView` (Camera previewview) and a `Canvas` that I draw on.

Here's a very simplified version of my code:

```
@Composable
fun ExerciseCanvasView(...) {
  Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    AndroidView(...)
    Canvas(...)
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to record a video of this function and save it into a file (video.mp4).

## What I've Tried:

- **MediaProjection**. I tried MediaProjection but is not what I want. It records the whole screen and I dont really need that and it might record sensitive info.
- **Drawing a composeview to a canvas to a bitmap.** I have tried this also, but the drawing has to be done in the Main UI Thread ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689903/animators-may-only-be-run-on-looper-threads-android#answer-37690090)) and this blocks the Main UI Thread, rendering it unusable.
- Some other deprecated shenanigans that chatgpt recommended that dont work at all.

For now, I dont care if even i have to save captures of the Composable and then encode them to a video or anything, I cant even make that to work...

## Question

Has anyone faced a similar issue and found a solution to record only this specific @Composable without blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Any solution other than the media projection APIs may result in a rather low frame rate. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I guess for now any result that does not use media projection is acceptable. Or even if there is a method to only record a @Composable function with media projection is welcomed.

Comment: You're welcome to look at [the official solution](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#composable-to-bitmap) and [this discussion of doing many of them in rapid succession using coroutines](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/15616709/is-there-any-kind-of-mutex-available-that-i-can-use-in-draww). You could also see if [this library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot), [this library](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/kapture), or [this library](https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable) will help.

Comment: However, if your objective is to *also* capture that `AndroidView()`, and that `AndroidView()` is a "Camera previewview", then none of those approaches are likely to work. The fact that you're trying to record a *video* of something that contains a "Camera previewview" suggests that you are trying to create a video from a camera that contains an overlay via this technique... and capturing bitmaps probably is not the best solution for that problem.

Comment: Oh, @CommonsWare you're right. Although I have seen the discussion you linked, you are right about probably not being the best solution. In fact, I want to record a video and apply like, lets call it a"instagram filter". I want to how it to the user real time but also record it and save to a file. I thought the question might be the best solution, but it might be better to separately record the video and apply the overlay after... Thank you so much.